# Read and return a Firebase Database entry that can also be used to update

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a record from the database and then use what was returned to also update the record. When I push a record into the database, it returns an object that I can also use to update it.

```
/* this works */
var result = firebase.database().ref('b').push({ name: 'levi' });
result.update({name: 'leeeevi'});
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the record using the ID, that returns an object that can be used to update the record? Something like the following:

```
var response = firebase.database().ref('/b/' + id).once('value');
response.update({name: 'Levi'});
```

I would like for a user to be able to read from the database using the ID of the entry. Then I would like for them to be able to make changes to the record in the database.

Comment: This is an Android Example, I think it should help you based on the replays you have got so far https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/10839/how-to-get-push-key-value-from-firebase-database/32507/android-example#t=201707281441153810515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push()` returns a new data path reference through which you can access the unique key/id that is generated. You can also use the same to  set data to it.

To get the unique key

```
// Get the unique key generated by push()
var pushId = pushRef.key;
var responseRef = firebase.database().ref('/b/' + pushId);
responseRef.update({name: 'Levi'});
```

Comment: That still won't work. In this case `once()` return a promise, which doesn't have an `update()` method.

Comment: Aah yes! My bad. Corrected and updated answer. Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thank you both! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As Joel says, calling [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) returns a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) to the database location. And a `Reference` has a method [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update).

Calling [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) returns a [`Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise), which does not have a method called `update()`.

It's not needed to call `once()`, you can just call `update()` directly on the ref:

```
firebase.database().ref('/b/' + id).update({name: 'Levi'});
```